# Tyring to run VSTS agent thru a proxy which limits sites

Tags: azure-devops

Have installed VSTS agent in a very locked down environment. It makes a connection to VSTS, gets job but fails when downloading artefact. Gives error
Error: in getBuild, so retrying => retries pending  : 4.
It retries 4 times and fails.

The agent is going thru a proxy. Have setup the proxy using ./config --proxyurl and also set HTTP_PROXY AND HTTPS_PROXY system environment vars.

The proxy is very limiting in that URLS are locked down, there is no authentication required. Does anybody know what URLs the agent accesses? Am hoping if can get a definitive list this will solve the issue. If anybody knows how can get a list would be great. Or maybe I have misconfigured?

Any ideas?

Comment: See: https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-what-domains-are-used-by-your-account/

Comment: Does the below answer and the link in jessehouwing's comment can help you solve the puzzle? You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it indeed help you. Or if you still facing any other issue or puzzle, feel free to leave comment there:-)

Answer (score 0):

> Tyring to run VSTS agent thru a proxy which limits sites

According to the document

[I'm running a firewall and my code is in Azure Repos. What URLs does the agent need to communicate with?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#im-running-a-firewall-and-my-code-is-in-azure-repos-what-urls-does-the-agent-need-to-communicate-with):

> To ensure your organization works with any existing firewall or IP
>   restrictions, ensure that `dev.azure.com` and `dev.azure.com` are open
>   and update your allow-listed IPs to include the following IP
>   addresses, based on your IP version. If you're currently allow-listing
>   the `13.107.6.183` and `13.107.9.183` IP addresses, leave them in place,
>   as you don't need to remove them.

And With just the organization's name or ID, you can get its base URL using the global Resource Areas REST API (https://dev.azure.com/_apis/resourceAreas). This API doesn't require authentication and provides information about the location (URL) of the organization as well as the base URL for REST APIs, which can live on different domains.

Please check this document [Best practices for working with URLs in Azure DevOps extensions and integrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/work-with-urls?view=azure-devops&tabs=http) for some more details.

Hope this helps.